# How to select only rows which having the values excluding the column which have the value 0 in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data set with having columns user_id, photo_taken,phot_uploaded, and photo_upload_error. For every user there is count for photo_taken,phot_uploaded, and photo_upload_error. like [Picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znNOr.png)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
    user_id| photo_taken|phot_uploaded|photo_upload_erro|
-------------------------------------------------------------
34645654645|     6      |        7    |         9       |
65543545435|     0      |        0    |         0       |
65455545435|     0      |        0    |         0       |
44553535435|     1      |        1    |         1       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

### I want to take columns that having the values and I want to exclude the columns which have the value 0.

```
    user_id| photo_taken|phot_uploaded|photo_upload_erro|
-------------------------------------------------------------
34645654645|     6      |        7    |         9       |
44553535435|     1      |        1    |         1       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this question really has two questions in one! I answered them separately - see below - [how to select only rows which having the values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66843672/5221944) and [want to exclude the columns which have the value 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66844243/5221944) . Hope you will be able to combine them together :o)  should be extremely easy task so I am leaving it for you!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to exclude *(rows* where all the values are `0`.  If that is the case:

```
select t.*
from t
where photo_taken > 0 or phot_uploaded > 0 or photo_upload_erro > 0;
```

Actually, it is not clear if you want to filter out rows where *all* values are `0` or *any* values.  The above does *any* value.  For all values, change the `or` to `and`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to select only rows which having the values ...

Consider below option - it DOES NOT require explicit mentioning of all the columns to be checked which can be quite handy if you have more than just few

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table` t
where translate(format('%t',(select as struct * except(user_id) from unnest([t]))),'0, ','')!='()'
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to exclude the columns which have the value 0 [ ... in all rows ...]

Consider below

```
execute immediate (
  select 'select ' || string_agg(col, ', ' order by offset) || ' from `project.dataset.table`' 
  from (
    select distinct offset, col,
      logical_and(val = '0') over(partition by col) all_zeroes
    from `project.dataset.table` t,
    unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv with offset,
    unnest([struct(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] as col, split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as val)])
  )
  where not all_zeroes
)
```

if to apply to below data

[image]

the output will be

[image]

as you can see  - the column `photo_taken` is excluded because it has all zeroes